# How to test Terraform files

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, terraform

I'm defining my infrastructure in Terraform files. I like Terraform a lot, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to test. I have `awspec`, which is really nice and runs RSpec-like tests against the result of your build via the AWS API. But is there a way to do unit tests, like on the results of `terraform plan`? What kind of workflow are others using with Terraform?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to test? I have a few things that I do to test Terraform modules (such as what the module should do given some input) and then there's things like `awspec` or `kitchen` for checking that things have been created in AWS.

Comment: did you try this: https://github.com/newcontext-oss/kitchen-terraform

Comment: @ydaetskcoR that's what I'm looking for. I'd love to have something that tests the module in isolation (a unit test that asserts against `terraform plan` or similar), as well as something that tests the built results on AWS. The latter will probably be a Test Kitchen build/test/destroy cycle.

Comment: I don't have anything I can share just yet (it needs a lot more work and some more battle testing) but I've not seen anything else do it just yet. Gruntworks have a framework called `terratest` that they have yet to open source but sounds like it might do something similar from the little I've read about it. Not sure if there's anything else out there like it though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to expand on Begin's answer with more information about Kitchen-Terraform.

[Kitchen-Terraform](https://newcontext-oss.github.io/kitchen-terraform) is a set of open source plugins that run within [Test-Kitchen](http://kitchen.ci/), these are supposed to go into your Terraform module repository to test that module's functionality before being used in a repository that creates the resources. Please feel free to check the documentation of those two projects for more details, but I will go through my recommendations for integration testing your Terraform code.

Install Ruby, Terraform
For this example, the Terraform module repo will be called: `my_terraform_module`

```
mkdir -p my_terraform_module
cd my_terraform_module

mkdir -p test/integration/kt_suite/controls \
         test/fixtures/tf_module/
```

Create a `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org/" do
  gem "kitchen-terraform"
end
```

Install the necessary components (uses the `Gemfile` for the dependencies of `kitchen-terraform`)

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Create the Test-Kitchen file `.kitchen.yml` - this brings together the testing frame, Test-Kitchen and Kitchen-Terraform

```
---
driver:
  name: terraform
  root_module_directory: test/fixtures/tf_module
  parallelism: 4

provisioner:
  name: terraform

transport:
  name: ssh

verifier:
  name: terraform
  groups:
    - name: basic
      controls:
        - file_check
        - state_file

platforms:
  - name: terraform

suites:
  - name: kt_suite
```

Your Terraform code should be at the root of the Terraform module repository such as:

```
my_terraform_module/
  |-- main.tf
```

Example code that can go in `main.tf`

```
resource "null_resource" "create_file" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo 'this is my first test' > foobar"
  }
}
```

Then we reference the Terraform module just like we would in [Terraform live repos](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example) - but in a test fixture instead in this file: `test/fixtures/tf_module/main.tf`

```
module "kt_test" {
  source = "../../.."
}
```

Then from there, you can run Terraform apply, but it's done a little differently with Kitchen-Terraform and Test-Kitchen, you run a converge which helps keep track of state and a couple other items.

```
bundle exec kitchen converge
```

Now you've seen your Terraform code do an apply, we need to test it. We can test the actual resources that were created, which would be like an integration test, but we can also test the state file, which is a semi unit test, but I am not aware of anything that can currently do unit tests against the HCL code of Terraform.

Create an inspec default profile file: `test/integration/kt_suite/inspec.yml`

```
---
name: default
```

Create an Inspec control for your integration testing: `test/integration/kt_suite/controls/basic.rb` - I'm using a test for the example Terraform code I used earlier for the `main.tf`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

control "file_check" do
  describe file('.kitchen/kitchen-terraform/kt-suite-terraform/foobar') do
    it { should exist }
  end
end
```

And this is an example test of pulling information from the state file and testing if something exists in it. This is a basic one, but you can definitely exand on this example.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

terraform_state = attribute "terraform_state", {}

control "state_file" do
  describe "the Terraform state file" do
    subject do json(terraform_state).terraform_version end

    it "is accessible" do is_expected.to match /\d+\.\d+\.\d+/ end
  end
end
```

Then run Inspec controls with Test-Kitchen and Kitchen-Terraform:

```
bundle exec kitchen verify
```

I took a lot of this from the getting started guide and some of the tutorials over here: https://newcontext-oss.github.io/kitchen-terraform/getting_started.html

Comment: I know we're not supposed to say 'thanks' in these, but this was super helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

We recently open sourced [Terratest](https://blog.gruntwork.io/open-sourcing-terratest-a-swiss-army-knife-for-testing-infrastructure-code-5d883336fcd5), our swiss army knife for testing infrastructure code.

Today, you're probably testing all your infrastructure code manually by deploying, validating, and undeploying. Terratest helps you automate this process:

1. Write tests in Go.
2. Use helpers in Terratest to execute your real IaC tools (e.g., Terraform, Packer, etc.) to deploy real infrastructure (e.g., servers) in a real environment (e.g., AWS).
3. Use helpers in Terratest to validate that the infrastructure works correctly in that environment by making HTTP requests, API calls, SSH connections, etc.
4. Use helpers in Terratest to undeploy everything at the end of the test.

Here's an example test for some Terraform code:

```
terraformOptions := &terraform.Options {
  // The path to where your Terraform code is located
  TerraformDir: "../examples/terraform-basic-example",
}

// This will run `terraform init` and `terraform apply` and fail the test if there are any errors
terraform.InitAndApply(t, terraformOptions)

// At the end of the test, run `terraform destroy` to clean up any resources that were created
defer terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptions)

// Run `terraform output` to get the value of an output variable
instanceUrl := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "instance_url")

// Verify that we get back a 200 OK with the expected text
// It can take a minute or so for the Instance to boot up, so retry a few times
expected := "Hello, World"
maxRetries := 15
timeBetweenRetries := 5 * time.Second
http_helper.HttpGetWithRetry(t, instanceUrl, 200, expected, maxRetries, timeBetweenRetries)
```

These are integration tests, and depending on what you're testing, can take 5 - 50 minutes. It's not fast (though using [Docker](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest#iterating-locally-using-docker) and [test stages](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest#iterating-locally-using-test-stages), you can speed *some* things up), and you'll have to work to make the tests reliable, but it is well worth the time.

Check out the [Terratest repo](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest#iterating-locally-using-test-stages) for docs and lots of examples of various types of infrastructure code and the corresponding tests for them.

Comment: I've also written a blog post that walks through testing one of my example projects with Terratest in more detail: https://brightfame.co/blog/testing-your-terraform-project-with-terratest/ - It may be of value to anyone. Cheers, Rob!

Answer (score 3):

From my research this is a tough issue, since Terraform is not meant to be a full featured programming language and you are declaring what resources you want with Terraform, not how to build them, trying to unit-test doesn't really give you the assurance you are building resources how you'd like without actually running an apply. This makes attempts to unit-test feel more like a linting to me.

However, you could parse your HCL files with something like [pyhcl](https://github.com/virtuald/pyhcl), or parse you're plan files, however from my experience this was a lot of work for little benefit (but I could be missing an easier method!).

Here are some alternatives if you wanted to test the results of your terraform applys:

[kitchen-terraform](https://github.com/newcontext-oss/kitchen-terraform) is a tool for writing [Test Kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen) specs for your infrastructure.

[kitchen-verifier-awspec](https://github.com/neillturner/kitchen-verifier-awspec) helps bring together `awspec` and `kitchen-terraform`, although I have not used it personally.

If you are using AWS, I have found [AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/) to be able to provide a lot of the same benefits as other infrastructure testing tools, without as much setup/maintenance. Although it is fairly new, and I have not used it extensively.

Also if you are paying for [Terraform Premium](https://www.hashicorp.com/products/terraform) you get access to [Sentinel](https://www.hashicorp.com/sentinel), which seems to provide a lot of similar benefits to AWS Config, however I have not used it personally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What exactly does Test Kitchen do? It appears that it is a generalized framework for provisioning, verifying, and destroying a set of resources--is that correct? It looks interesting but I'm not sure it's what I need--what I'm looking for is fast unit tests to complement my awspec integration tests.

Comment: Yes that is what Test Kitchen does, so it will not help with any faster unit-testing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers, I will add my two cents. I was not very happy using GO lang with [Terratest](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest) although it works perfectly well. It is just that GO is not my favorite programming language. I looked for some frameworks in Java and I found [terraform-maven](https://github.com/deliveredtechnologies/terraform-maven). At first glance, I only found [examples in Groovy](https://github.com/deliveredtechnologies/terraform-maven/tree/develop/examples), but since Groovy run on JVM, it is feasible to implement the same examples in Java.

I translated part of the [S3PreProvisionSpec.groovy](https://github.com/deliveredtechnologies/terraform-maven/blob/develop/examples/tf-pre-post-infra-test/src/test/groovy/tf/s3_pre_post_demo/S3PreProvisionSpec.groovy) to Java. It is testing this [main.tf](https://github.com/deliveredtechnologies/terraform-maven/blob/develop/examples/tf-pre-post-infra-test/src/main/tf/s3_pre_post_demo/main.tf) file.

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class S3PreProvisionTest {

    private final String TF_CHANGE = "change";
    private final String TF_AFTER = "after";
    private final String TF_TAGS = "tags";
    private final Map<String, String> mandatoryTags = Map.of(
        "application_id", "cna",
        "stack_name", "stacked",
        "created_by", "f.gutierrez@yieldlab.de"
    );
    private Terraform terraform;
    private TfPlan tfplan;

    @BeforeAll
    void setup() {
        terraform = new Terraform().withRootDir("s3_pre_post_demo")
        // .withProperties(Map.of("noColor", "true"))
        ;
        tfplan = terraform.initAndPlan();
    }

    @AfterAll
    void cleanup() {
        terraform.destroy();
    }

    @Test
    void mandatoryTagsForS3Resources() {
        List<Map> s3Bucket = tfplan.getResourcesByType("aws_s3_bucket");
        System.out.println("=========================");

        s3Bucket.forEach(map -> {
            Map tfChangeMap = (Map) map.get(TF_CHANGE);
            Map tfAfterMap = (Map) tfChangeMap.get(TF_AFTER);
            Map tfTagsMap = (Map) tfAfterMap.get(TF_TAGS);

            assertEquals(3, tfTagsMap.size());
            mandatoryTags.forEach((k, v) -> {
                assertEquals(v, tfTagsMap.get(k));
            });

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(map);
                JSONObject jsonChange = jsonObject.getJSONObject(TF_CHANGE);
                JSONObject jsonAfter = jsonChange.getJSONObject(TF_AFTER);
                JSONObject jsonTags = jsonAfter.getJSONObject(TF_TAGS);
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + jsonTags.toString());
                mandatoryTags.forEach((k, v) -> {
                    try {
                        assertEquals(v, jsonTags.getString(k));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to output the results to a file using `-out=tempfile`, then run a script to validate whatever you're trying to do, and if all passes you can pass the file into the apply command.
look at `-out` here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but it appears that the `.plan` files are binary--do you know if there's a way to parse them with Ruby?

Comment: rather than trying to read the .plan bin file why not run terraform plan through ruby then parse the output of the command?

Comment: It's an awkward parse, but it's a possibility.

Comment: @DavidHam wrote down my experience with tfjson in a full answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use  github.com/palantir/tfjson to parse a `.plan` file to `json`.

There is an issue at the moment that give a **"unknown plan file version: 2"** error. This is because the vendored version of terraform is too old.

The fix is:

```
go get github.com/palantir/tfjson
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/palantir/tfjson
rm -rf vendor
go get -v ./...
```

There is then an error in `../../hashicorp/terraform/config/testing.go`. To fix just change the line

```
t.Helper()
```

to

```
//t.Helper()
```

Run `go get` again and then `go install`

```
go get -v ./...
go install ./...
```

You should then be able to do the following which will produce `json` output.

```
terraform plan --out=terraform.plan 
tfjson terraform.plan
```

Comment: The `t.Helper()` issue is probably because you're running Golang <1.9 as `Helper` is introduced in 1.9

Comment: Thankyou, I was using 1.8 at the time.